# C++ slicing and virtual destructors

Tags: c++, slice, virtual-destructor

I get a vector of raw pointers, which I copy. The ownership of the objects pointed by these pointers belong to some other module. I have to replace some of the pointers with new ones which point to newly created objects. So in the end I will have a vector with pointers on which I need to call delete and others on which I do not. My idea was to introduce new classes which make this automatic.

```
template <typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>>
class Pointer {
public:
    Pointer(T p) : pointer_(p) {}
    virtual ~Pointer() = default;

    T operator->()  { return pointer_; }

protected:
    T pointer_;
};

template <typename T>
class NotOwnedPointer : public Pointer<T> {
public:
    NotOwnedPointer(T p) : Pointer<T>(p) {}
    ~NotOwnedPointer() { std::cout << "not owned\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
class OwnedPointer : public Pointer<T> {
public:
    OwnedPointer(T p) : Pointer<T>(p) {}
    ~OwnedPointer() { std::cout << "owned\n"; delete this->pointer_; this->pointer_ = nullptr; }
    OwnedPointer(const OwnedPointer&) = delete;
    OwnedPointer& operator=(const OwnedPointer& other) = delete;
};

struct Foo {
    int i;
};

int main() {
    Foo* foo = new Foo{42};
    std::vector<Pointer<Foo*>> v;
    v.push_back(NotOwnedPointer(foo));
    v.push_back(OwnedPointer(foo));
}
```

Note that I use `Pointer` for the vector type instead of `Pointer*`. This way slicing will happen when I add a derived class instance to the vector.

Which destructors will be called when the vector is destructed? Since the type of the vector is `Pointer` I would say that the virtual table for class `Pointer` will be used and `~Pointer()` will be called, but when I run the program it prints the text from `~NotOwnedPointer()` and `~OwnedPointer()`.

Comment: The destructor of the templated class `Pointer` is virtual.   `delete this->pointer_` will therefore invoke the destructors corresponding to the actual type (i.e. of the most derived class, and it's bases, in reverse order of construction i.e. base class last).

Comment: "I get a vector of raw pointers, which I copy. The ownership of the objects pointed by these pointers belong to some other module" - raw pointers should never be "owning pointers" - use smart pointers for that (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`). Raw pointers *should* only ever be "observing pointers" without ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v.push_back(NotOwnedPointer(foo));
v.push_back(OwnedPointer(foo));
```

These two lines create temporary objects (of type `NotOwnedPointer` and `OwnedPointer`, respectively), which are then sliced and copied into the vector.

When the temporary objects are destroyed, their destructors are called (`~NotOwnedPointer()` and `~OwnedPointer()`, respectively). This has nothing to do with `v`, which is destroyed later.